# ubuntu (12.10) wants to reinstall everytime I boot

Tags: installation, boot

I installed Ubuntu 12.10 and Windows on my computer. However, on booting Ubuntu always asks me:

1. "try ubuntu without installing"
2. "Install ubuntu"

What's going on, or what did I do wrong during installation?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Have you tried removing the installation medium from your PC? (CD/DVD, USB flash drive). It appears to be booting from the installation medium.

Comment: Please add some details about how you installed it. Also, make sure you did not leave the live cd in the optical drive. My guess is that you are booting the live cd.

Comment: You just need to tell the bios to boot from your hard drive now you have installed it. I suspect you didn't go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This is easy:

- Turn off your computer
- Turn it back on
- While it's booting up, press F12. (If that doesn't work, experiment a bit. Try all the F# keys. DEL sometimes does stuff.)
- Now, choose to boot from hard disk.
- Your Ubuntu should be booted normally. Eject the CD from the drive as soon as possible.
- Don't leave a Live CD in your computer if you're not going to use it.